# Why do i get a NullPointerException when I have checked for the the String not being null?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, equals

My app crashes on a NPE even though i'm checking whether the value of the String is non null:

```
  if (AppConstants.AppConstants_appName != null &&
            AppConstants.AppConstants_appName.equals("xxx")) {
            suffix = "version=1.0";
        }
```

AppConstants_appName is a public static String.
Not sure what's going wrong here.
Here's my Stacktrace. Anyone an idea?

Stacktrace

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at nl.onlineretailservice.library.APIManager.getURLSuffix(APIManager.java:637)
at nl.onlineretailservice.library.APIManager.requestFolderProducts(APIManager.java:334)
at nl.onlineretailservice.helper.FolderViewerActivityHelper.loadProducts(FolderViewerActivityHelper.java:160)
at nl.onlineretailservice.helper.FolderViewerActivityHelper$2.downloadReady(FolderViewerActivityHelper.java:267)
at nl.onlineretailservice.library.DownloadOperation.onPostExecute(DownloadOperation.java:221)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Maybe  `AppConstants` is null so you also have to check for `AppConstants != null`?

Comment: What happens if you use an assert?

Comment: check `if( AppConstants != null )` first

Comment: But AppConstants_appName is a public static string so it can be accessed whether or not there is there is an AppConstants instance, no? Then why would i need to check whether AppConstants != null? And besides that the first condition of the if statement has been passed making sure that AppConstants.AppConstants_appName != null only to tell me at the next conditional check (.equals) that the variable is null. I don't understand that

Comment: @LBesancon: I haven't been able to reproduce the crash myself, so i guess i can't really tell you what happens with an assert. Code seems to work just fine in test environment, though from crash report on Play it occasionally crashes at this point (250 crashes so far)

Comment: @RikvanVelzen I would still use an assert in a next version and check if you get any difference in the number of crashes (which I think you will)

Comment: @LBesancon: thnx for the tip. I'll check it out.

Comment: @RikvanVelzen you're welcome. Please post the state of it all. I'm really interesting in getting what the problem could be there and if asserts can solve it

Comment: Post the stack trace. You clearly aren't getting the NPE where you think you are.

Comment: That code fragment should work. It's a bit of a problem if the issue can't be reproduced. My guess is that the code producing the crash report is not your most current code, the exception is not on the line you think it is or the code you posted is not the same as your actual code.